# b a and sos filter order different in case of filtfilt?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I am aware that using filtfilt (e.g. in Python via scipy or in Matlab) I will apply the filter bidirectional. Setting up the b, a parameters based on a 4th order filter will effectively result in an 8th order filter.

I believe that creating the same 4th order filter with sos output and using sosfiltfilt will not change the filter order and should result in a 4th order filter (not an 8th order). Is that correct?

TLDR: Is forward-backward filtering in case of sosfiltfilt also doubling the filter order like in filtfilt?

Comment: *"Is forward-backward filtering in case of sosfiltfilt also doubling the filter order like in filtfilt?"*  Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using forward-backward filtering, whether it is using the b,a parameter form or the sos form, doubles the effective order of the filtering when compared to a simple forward filter. That is the reason why [`scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt.html)'s example compares a 4th-order Butterworth filter using `sosfiltfilt` with an 8th-order Butterworth filter using `sosfilt`.